# current_user is nil in user controller's show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I took over a rails project where an admin can create users.
The authentication is done with the devise gem.

Once the normal user is logged in, everything works fine. The `current_user` variable holds my user. But when I try to access the user's profile over this link `<%= link_to "My profile", user_path(current_user) %>` leading to `User#show`. I get an error that the `current_user` is nil.

I don't understand why suddenly, the `current_user` is nil.

```
#user_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_user, only:[:destroy, :edit, :show, :update, :check_bonus]
  before_action :reset_session, except:[:show, :check_bonus]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

I really have no clue what to look for. At some points, the session gets restored (`session[:validated] = false`), but not in the User#show action.

Comment: Please share complete code of user_controller

Comment: Guessing your `user_controller` isn't inheriting from a controller that performs the authentication check. Hard to say without seeing your full `user_controller`

Comment: I added the beginning of the controller. It doesn't inherit from any devise controller indeed. Could that be the problem?

Comment: also add `set_user` method's code here @Clara